# Check the invertibility of a $8\times 8$ matrix over $\Bbb Z_2$ by hand

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the efficient way to check the invertibility of a $8\times 8$ matrix over $\Bbb Z_2$, say

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&1&0&0&1\\1&1&0&0&0&1&0&0\\0&1&1&0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&1&1&0&0&0&1\\1&0&0&1&1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&1&0&0&1&1\end{bmatrix}\in\mathcal{M}_{8\times 8}(\Bbb Z_2)$?

Gauss elimination is somehow painful I think. Is it better to do it by checking $\det$ or the linear independence of the column vectors? If so, how?

Comment: Hmm - I didn't realize that the 3x3 trick doesn't generalize! @joriki

Comment: From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix), we know that the eigenvalues of this matrix are $1+\omega^4+\omega^{7}$, where $\omega$ is a root of $p(x)=x^7+x^6+\ldots+x+1$.  However $p(x)=(x+1)^7$ over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (if $\mathbb{Z}_2$ means $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$), so this matrix has only one eigenvalue: $1+1^4+1^7=1$.  Therefore it is invertible.

Comment: You can also write this matrix as $I+N$ with $N$ nilpotent.  So the inverse is $I-N+N^2-\ldots-N^7$.